# Delete NAs, based on duplicated ID variables

Tags: r, data-manipulation, missing-data

My data looks something like this

```
zz <- 'wb_iso3c                   country year wbclass
1:      YUG "Serbia and Montenegro (former)" 1990    NA
2:      YUG            "Yugoslavia (former)" 1990      UM
3:      YUG "Yugoslavia (former)" 1991    NA
4:      YUG            "Serbia and Montenegro (former)" 1991      UM
5:      YUG "Serbia and Montenegro (former)" 1992      NA
6:      YUG            "Yugoslavia (former)" 1992    NA'
Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

I would like to find a way to systematically and efficiently drop observations when:
My observation is duplicated only considering `wb_iso3c` and `year`. (hence I do not care if another variable such as `country` has different values). Among the "duplicated" observations, I would like to keep
the observation where `wbclass` is not `NA`. If
`wbclass` is `NA` for both observations, it is indifferent which row to keep.

The final dataset should look something like this

```
   wb_iso3c                        country year wbclass
1:      YUG            Yugoslavia (former) 1990      UM
2:      YUG Serbia and Montenegro (former) 1991      UM
3:      YUG Serbia and Montenegro (former) 1992    <NA>
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help. If you can use data.table of dyplr it would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dplyr` you could try the following.

First `group_by` both `wb_iso3c` and `year`, with intent on obtaining one observation for each distinct combination of these two columns.

Then `arrange` (sort order) the `wbclass` column within the group. With `arrange`, the `NA` values will always be sorted to the end.

Then `slice(1)` will keep the first row of data in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

Data %>%
  group_by(wb_iso3c, year) %>%
  arrange(wbclass) %>%
  slice(1)
```

**Output**

```
  wb_iso3c country                         year wbclass
  <chr>    <chr>                          <int> <chr>  
1 YUG      Yugoslavia (former)             1990 UM     
2 YUG      Serbia and Montenegro (former)  1991 UM     
3 YUG      Serbia and Montenegro (former)  1992 NA
```

Answer (score 2):

A very long `base R` solution can be based on testing for duplicated values and then computing a variable to store dupes and `NA`. After that you can filter and get the expected result. Here the code:

```
#Code
Data$i1 <- duplicated(paste(Data$wb_iso3c,Data$year),fromLast = T)
Data$i2 <- ifelse(Data$i1 & is.na(Data$wbclass),1,0)
Data2 <- Data[Data$i2==0,]
Data2$i1 <- NULL
Data2$i2 <- NULL
```

Output:

```
   wb_iso3c                        country year wbclass
2:      YUG            Yugoslavia (former) 1990      UM
4:      YUG Serbia and Montenegro (former) 1991      UM
6:      YUG            Yugoslavia (former) 1992    <NA>
```